# Removing PropertyGroup during Nuget uninstall.ps1

Tags: powershell, nuget

I've got a Nuget package that adds some MSBuild entries to the project XML during install. This works fine, producing the following (among other entries):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <JsCompilationToolsPath>some/path/determined/at/runtime</JsCompilationToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

However, I'm having trouble removing the property (and its resulting group element) during uninstall. My PowerShell-fu leaves a lot to be desired, but so far I've tried a few approaches:

1. Removing all PropertyGroup elements which have at least one Property element named `JsCompilationToolsPath`;
2. Removing all Property elements named `JsCompilationToolsPath` and then removing all PropertyGroup elements that have no child elements;
3. Just removing the named Property objects.

Here's the latter attempt:

```
$msBuildProject.Properties | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "JsCompilationToolsPath" } | ForEach-Object { $msBuildProject.RemoveProperty($_) }
```

None of the approaches have any effect; the script runs without error but the property elements aren't removed.

What's the right way to remove MSBuild properties via PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

function RemoveMatchingPropertyGroups($buildProject, $property)
{
    foreach ($pg in $buildProject.Xml.PropertyGroups)
    {
        $firstChild = $pg.FirstChild.Name
        if ($property -eq $firstChild)
        {
            Write-Host "Removing old $firstChild"
            try
            {
                $pg.Parent.RemoveChild($pg)
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
} 

Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.Build, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
$buildProject = [Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection]::GlobalProjectCollection.GetLoadedProjects($project.FullName) | Select-Object -First 1

RemoveMatchingPropertyGroups $buildProject "JsCompilationToolsPath"
```

You basically need to load the msbuild engine dll, then loop over all the property groups and if the `PropertyGroup.FirstChild.Name` matches you can delete the propertygroup. This is done by calling `PropertyGroup.Parent.RemoveChild()` The `Parent` needs to be there because you want to remove the propertygroup itself, and not just the property.